# Seleccionar un valor de un select iterado con foreach

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Buenas tardes estoy iterando unas opciones en un select, pero quiero hacer algo diferente, es decir si existe el campo en la base de datos que es igual me seleccionas ese, de lo contrario quiero poder seleccionar yo uno que es el id 30.

```
<select class="form-control myinputs col-12 selectBusca" name="vendedor" id="vendedor">
   <option value="0"> Selecciona un vendedor </option>
      @foreach ($comercialesVenta as $comerVenta)
        @if ($equipo->vendedor_id == null)
          //si este campo es null en la base de datos quiero poder seleccionar una yo del selector para que salga marcado
          
        @else
          Si el campo no es null, me selecciona comparando la tabla, esto me funciona bien
          <option value="{{ $comerVenta->id }}" {{ ( $comerVenta->id== $equipo->vendedor_id) ? 'selected' : '' }}> {{ $comerVenta->name }} {{ $comerVenta->apellidos }} </option>
        @endif
                                        
      @endforeach
</select>
```

La parte de comparar me funciona bien, si existe me marca en el select el que toca, pero como puedo hacer el de arriba, si el campo es null quiero poder dejar seleccionado uno siempre y que puedan elegir si quieren cambiar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se me ocurre que como antes del foreach ya puedes saber si `$equipo->vendedor_id == null`, puedes asignar el valor a seleccionar en una variable.

Por ejemplo:

```
@php($vendedor_id = $equipo->vendedor_id ?? 30)
```

De esa forma, cuando estés dentro del foreach, haces la comparación con esa variable:

```
<option value="{{ $comerVenta->id }}" @if( $comerVenta->id == $vendedor_id ) selected @endif > {{ $comerVenta->name }} {{ $comerVenta->apellidos }} </option>
```

En tu código, algo así:

```
@php($vendedor_id = $equipo->vendedor_id ?? 30)
<select class="form-control myinputs col-12 selectBusca" name="vendedor" id="vendedor">
   @foreach ($comercialesVenta as $comerVenta)
      <option value="{{ $comerVenta->id }}" @if( $comerVenta->id == $vendedor_id ) selected @endif > {{ $comerVenta->name }} {{ $comerVenta->apellidos }} </option>              
   @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: Perfecto @porloscerros Ψ es perfecto, muchas gracias!